# Travesing the DOM - Alphabetically

Tags: javascript

I have a list of links/image pairs in a page.

For example, social page below has two links - Twitter, Facebook...the image didn't capture the name.

I need to traverse these and do and insert alphabetically.

So I grab the page ID as follows:

```
var element_iterator = document.getElementById( 'social_page' );
```

Now I have the "page' containing the two links Twiiter and Facebook.  Say i want to inset Quora, how do I traverse this to find the insert point.

How can I traverse the DOM and to and alphaetical insert based on title.

**Broken Code**

```
var page_element = document.getElementById( form_elements.tag.value + '_page' );
var element_iterator = page_element.firstChild;    
while( !!( element_iterator = element_iterator.nextSibling ) )
{
    if( typeof element_iterator.tagName === 'undefined' )
    {
        page_element.insertBefore( image_element, element_iterator );
        page_element.insertBefore( link_element, element_iterator );
        break;
    }
    else if( element_iterator.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a' && ( link_element.innerHTML<element_iterator.innerHTML ) )
    {
        element_iterator = element_iterator.previousSibling;
        page_element.insertBefore( image_element, element_iterator );
        page_element.insertBefore( link_element, element_iterator );
        break;
    }
}
```

[image: DOM]

Comment: "I need to traverse these and do and insert alphabetically." What are you inserting? Also, I think I probably know the answer to this one, but: Are we restricted to regular Javascript or is jQuery an option?

Comment: You should show us the HTML source, not an IE developer tools screenshot.

Comment: Also, just a style tip, it's best to stick to the JavaScript convention of `camelCaseVariableNames`, not `underscore_delimited_ones`.

Comment: JavaScript functions are variables, which is why we use the same convention for both. E.g. `var getMeStuff = 1 > 0 ? document.getElementById : document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: well var is not actually a var...I would not say it is a function either...maybe  a vunction...but I get your point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have a list of DOM nodes, for example something like:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("bookmark_link");
```

(To get elements scoped to be subelements of a certain ID, try

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("#social_page .bookmark_link");
```

)

Let's say they have a property that you want to sort by, for example `innerText`:

```
links[0].innerText === "Twitter"
links[1].innerText === "Facebook"
// etc.
```

Here is how you would get a sorted array of those DOM nodes:

```
// Convert the NodeList to a normal array,
// since NodeList doesn't have a sort method.
var linksArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(links);

// Sort the array using a custom comparison function.
linksArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText);
});

// linksArray is now sorted.
```

Comment: @stack.user.0: You gotta show your code to get a useful answer

Comment: @stack.user.0 I assumed that you knew a way to get a `NodeList` of the elements you wanted, sorry. Updated to include one method of doing so.